# Any 8+ MP Nikon/Canon/Sony cam that can click photos via the PC?

Tags: digital, remote, windows

I'm looking for an economical still camera to click hi-res photos for a research project I'm doing.

An important requirement is that the photo output in a RAW format. (least compression)

I want to know which cameras would be suitable, that can be controlled (remote capture) from any software that works okay.

This is the list of cameras that [Lightroom](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/842/cpsid_84221.html) supports:

Canon

```
* EOS 5D
* EOS 5D Mark II
* EOS 1D Mark II
* EOS 1Ds Mark II
* EOS 1D Mark III
* EOS 1Ds Mark III
* EOS 1D Mark IV
* EOS 7D
* EOS 500D (Rebel T1I(EOS /Kiss X3 Digital)
* EOS 450D (Rebel XSI/EOS Kiss X2)
* EOS 1000D (Rebel XS/EOS Kiss F)
* EOS 350D (Rebel XT/EOS Kiss Digital N)
* EOS 400D (Rebel XTi/EOS Kiss Digital X)
* EOS 20D
* EOS 30D
* EOS 40D
* EOS 50D
```

Nikon

```
* D3
* D3s
* D3x
* D90
* D200
* D300
* D300s
* D700
* D5000
```

**Edit:** Found some more Nikon models listed on [this](http://thephotogeek.com/choosing-nikon-dslr-camera-tethered-shooting-software/) page:

```
* D2X
* D2Hs
* D2H
* D2Xs
* D100
* D80
* D70s
* D70
* D60
* D50
* D40X
* D40
```

Most of these are very expensive so I'm looking for cheaper alternatives that could offer similar quality and resolution of photos.

1. Are these the only Nikon and Canon cams that have remote capture?
2. Does **Sony** have any suitable models?

Comment: It seems like you've generally answered your own question. Amongst the cameras you have listed, prices range anywhere from a few hundred dollars to several thousand dollars...you can pretty much take your pick for whatever your price range is.

Comment: What sort of budget were you looking at?

Comment: What sort of project are you doing?  If you're doing some kind of photon counting (rather than photography), you may want to go to a different kind of camera altogether, one that doesn't have a Bayer filter in front of the detector but captures all photons in the visible light range and can be filtered in front of the detector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to find a used Canon 20D or 30D for $250-350, or thereabouts, plus whatever lens you want.  Although it looks like Lightroom can control the camera directly, it would probably be a good idea to make sure you get the original Canon software CD with the camera (that's not necessarily a given w/ a used camera).

As far as the Nikons go, I've seen D40's selling in a similar price range.  I don't know that you're going to find much joy for less than that.

Comment: Canon make all of their software available to download from their website; although they are update tools, it is trivial to trick it enough to install, as I found out after losing the original CD that came with my 20D